# Why async function continues after await (in vuex)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, async-await, vuex

From one vuex action (`togglePostLike`) I'm trying to await another vuex action (`requiresAuth`) using async/await.

I had expected that if `return Promise.resolve()` was never called then the first action should get stopped at `await dispatch` (and get garbage collected), but it proceeds to the `console.log('this is called SECOND')` even without the resolve.

Shouldn't await stop the execution without resolve? How can I get that intended behavior?

**/store/modules/post.js**

```
async togglePostLike ({ dispatch, rootState }, post) {
    await dispatch('user/requiresAuth', null, { root: true })
    console.log('this is called SECOND, but why without resolve')
    // I don't want this stuff to execute without the resolve
    if (post.likes.includes(rootState.user._id)) {
      dispatch('addPostUnlike', post)
    } else {
      dispatch('addPostLike', post)
    }
},
```

**/store/modules/user.js**

```
async requiresAuth ({ state }) {
      if (!state.authenticated) {
         router.push({ name: 'login', query: { comeBack: true } })
         $(`.modal`).modal('hide')
         console.log('this is called first')
       } else {
         console.log('this is NOT called')
         return Promise.resolve()
       }
  },
```

**EDIT: how it looks without async/await**

As I understand from the [vuex docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/actions.html), `dispatch` returns a promise anyway. Using the following:

**post.js**

```
if (dispatch('user/requiresAuth', null, { root: true })) {
     // still executes before return false   
}
```

**user.js**

```
requiresAuth ({ state }) {
  if (!state.authenticated) {
     // do stuff (does it)
     return false
   }
   return true
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `async`/`await` at all here? There's nothing asynchronous in your code.

Comment: @Bergi because dispatch returns async anyway. So for instance, when you you take out the async, and try to `return false` into a conditional, it'll proceed regardless

Comment: But `requiresAuth` does not use `dispatch`? Also, to wait for the `dispatch` calls in `togglePostLike`, you would need to `return` or `await` their results.

Comment: The way I read that vuex documentation on actions, I have always assumed that an action would not return a `Promise` unless one was explicitly returned or unless the action method was `async`. But, fiddling around, I see that's not true: https://jsfiddle.net/h9y15r7m/. So, you're correct in that assumption. `dispatch('user/requiresAuth',...).then(result => if (result) { // do stuff })` should work in your edited example. https://jsfiddle.net/h9y15r7m/1/

Comment: @thanksd yea thanks d, ultimately the approach i took is the one you just wrote. Vuex docs does have an example of a dispatch with an explicitly returned promise so I'm still confused if there's a difference there, but I may need to just learn more about promises, thenables, etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `async function` like `requiresAuth` always returns a promise that is resolved with the return value (including `undefined` if no `return` statement is evaluated). It does not make a difference whether the function ends without a `return`, with a `return;`, with a `return undefined;`, with a `return Promise.resolve()` or with a `return Promise.resolve(undefined)` - they are indistinguishable from the outside.

Either return a boolean and then branch on it, or just throw an exception.

Comment: The root cause of confusion here, I believe, is that the Vuex `dispatch` method will (apparently) always return a `Promise`, even if the method being dispatched is not `async`.

Comment: Yes, you will need `if (await dispatch(…))`